# Create graph reports "no protocol" error message

Tags: neo4j

```
WITH "/Users/nlp/social_graph/graph-nodes.csv" as uri
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM uri as row
MERGE (:User {id: row.id})
```

I have a CSV file to contains some nodes, and I want to load it into neo4j through Neo4j Desktop, but got the following error message:

```
Invalid URL '/Users/nlp/social_graph/graph-nodes.csv': no protocol: /Users/nlp/social_graph/social-nodes.csv
```

What's the error? Note that before I run the command in the browser, the database is empty. How to load the database?

EDIT: Did some search and added 'file:///' to the file path, this time I got another message:

Couldn't load the external resource at: `file:/Users/congminmin/Library/Application%20Support/Neo4j%20Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-fdb13bea-33f7-409b-a6bd-387a25a679e6/installation-3.5.12/import/Users/congminmin/social_graph/social-nodes.csv`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to copy your cv file into the `import` directory under your neo4j installation directory. Then use `file:///social-nodes.csv` In your `LOAD CSV` command.
Find more details here: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

Comment: On my Mac, I installed the the Neo4j Desktop. Which directory is it installed to?

Comment: On the main page of the UI where you can create a graph, click on the Manage button of your graph, then under Terminal tab, you will see a terminal. Run a `pwd` and find the installation path

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but if you are using neo4j on docker, the import folder path is as follows:

`/var/lib/neo4j/import`

You can create a volume that bounds to the import directory. After mounting, copy your local files to your mounted directory, then use `file:///file-name` in your `LOAD` command.